# Show specific values on x axis ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame

```
  rank  min_v   max_var   cnt cnt_pct cnt_keshel keshel_pct
1     1  25650     81000 30751      10       2497        8.1
2     2  81000     99000 30751      10       2539        8.3
3     3  99000    112500 30751      10       2683        8.7
4     4 112500    135000 30751      10       2700        8.8
5     5 135000    147150 30751      10       2561        8.3
6     6 147150    162000 30751      10       2657        8.6
7     7 162000    180000 30751      10       2593        8.4
8     8 180000    225000 30751      10       2421        7.9
9     9 225000    270000 30751      10       2251        7.3
10   10 270000 117000000 30752      10       1923        6.3
```

I want to plot the variable cnt_pct with bars and the variable keshel_pct with a line ,the graph comes out just fine the problem is with the values that appear on  the x axis.For some reason I get values like 2.5,5,10 but I want to get 1-10.

This is how the graph looks like
[image]

I tries using the scale_x_continuous(breaks =c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100)) 
but this returns the following graph

[image]

The same thing happens with scale_x_discrete

Anybody has an idea where is my mistake?

Comment: What geom are you using? Where is your plotting code? Sounds like you probably want `geom_col()`.

Comment: You say "*I want to get 1-10*" but then the code you try is `scale_x_continuous(breaks =c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100))`. Of course these don't print (except the 10) because the max of your data is 10. The numbers 20, 30, etc. are all "off the edge". Instead, try `scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10)`. You can *label* them differently, for example `scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10, labels = (1:10) * 10)`, but their actual positions needs to use the same units as your data.

Comment: Thanks Gregor this worked fine